# is there a Syntax like MSSQL's "INSERT INTO table (fieldlist) OUTPUT INSERTED.id VALUES" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, qsqlquery

I like to get the id of the record that's been inserted by a statement **as a result of that statement**. I know about `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` but can not use it in my scenario because `LAST_INSERT_ID()` works on a per-connection-basis and I am currently using a convenient function in my framework to access the db - but that convenience implies that the connection only exists during execution of that statement - so I'm wondering if there is a syntax as in Microsoft SQL Server as shown in the title?

In my environment, I am building the command looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO Bookings (Status,YEarlyBird,YDays,YHotel,YBanquet,Name,Company,Address,Town,Region,Postcode,CountryCode,Second
Name,SecondEmail,RoomType,SpouseMealPlan,Notes,Conference_VAT,Accommodation_VAT,Conference_id,InvoiceAmount,Conferen
ceGross,Accomodation,SpouseGross,SpouseNet,TotalGross,TotalNet,ConferenceNet,Courses) VALUES (:<C1:,:<C1:,:<C6:,:<C
6:,:<C1:,:<C12:,:<C28:,:<C15:,:<C7:,:<C5:,:<C5:,:<C2:,:<C1:,:<C1:,:<C15:,:<C3:,:<C1:,:<F:,:<F:,:<I:,:<F:,:<F:,:<F:,:
      <F:,:<F:,:<F:,:<F:,:<F:,:<C1:);SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

(the :<:-stuff are placeholders for Bind-variables)
If a ran the INSERT on its own, it works. If I append the `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` as shown, I get:

```
[MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.18-log]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to y
      our MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()' at line 1
```

**P.S:** using that convient way to access the DB is perfectly ok in my use-case because the DB is written once only - exactly with the statement i am working on.

Comment: Why don't use stored procedure that inserts recorde and return last insert identificator through output parameter during one transaction?

Comment: would it be possible to send two queries in one string (the INSERT and the SELECT LADT_INSERT_ID() ) ?

Comment: @Jan: I tried to do "INSERT...;SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();" but that gave a "You have an error in your SQL syntax; "

Comment: @Alexander: insufficient permissions to set up SP...

Comment: could you edit your question and show that INSERT / SELECT thing your tried on the off chance, that there's something else broken with that SQL?

Comment: I don't see the ways to return any values using [INSERT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html). You need to use a user-defined variable or use a [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html) to put new key value to auxiliary table.